# Requested package goetas/xsd2php 2.0 exists as goetas/xsd2php[1.0 but these are rejected by your constraint

Tags: php, authorize.net

I have loaded composer via ssh in mygodaddy hosting and installed authorize.net php-sdk. I changed the composer.json based on instructions using latest hot fix [here](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/blob/d63a785803647e4d137a56cecb7c150e15c32fef/composer.json). When I do composer update, I am getting this error:

Problem 1

> - The requested package goetas/xsd2php 2.0.x-dev#fdc2ab0bb3f2b3ab796ca567cf8c0f3446a7ea3a exists as goetas/xsd2php[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-alpha, 2.1.0,
>     dev-goetas-runtime, dev-master, 2.1.x-dev, dev-official-serializer]
>     but these are rejected by your constraint.

I dont know where to fix this, please help..

Answer (score 1):

you should change in require-dev
from `"goetas/xsd2php": "2.*@dev",`
to `"goetas/xsd2php": "dev-master#fdc2ab0bb3f2b3ab796ca567cf8c0f3446a7ea3a",`

or use 1.8.9 sdk [version](https://packagist.org/packages/authorizenet/authorizenet#1.8.9)